# Number of BST's given a linked list of numbers

Tags: binary-search-tree

Suppose I have a linked list of positive numbers, how many BST's can be generated from them, provided **all nodes** all required to form the tree?

Conversely, how many BST's can be generated, provided **any number** of the linked list nodes can exist in these trees?

Bonus: how many balanced BST's can be formed? Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: okay, so an inorder traversal of BST's leads a sorted list right? so i thought that we could decompose the qn to "how many ways can a linked list be sorted". that would be nCn + nC(n-1) + ... + nC1, which would be the answer to the second question. the answer to the first qn would be n. third qn, im not entirely sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine number of possible tree from given Nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238440/determine-number-of-possible-tree-from-given-nodes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic programming to compute that.

Just note that it doesn't matter what the numbers are, just how many. In other words for any n distinct integers there is the same amount of different BSTs. Let's call this number f(n).

Then if you know f(k) for k < n, you can get f(n):

```
f(n) = Sum ( f(i) + f(n-1-i), i = 0,1,2,...,n-1 )
```

Each summand represents the number of trees for which the (1+i)-th smallest number is at the root (thus in the left subtree where are i numbers and in the right subtree there are n-1-i).
So DP solves this.

Now the total number of BSTs (with any nodes from the list) is just a sum:

```
Sum ( Binomial(n,k) * f(k), k=1,2,3,...,n )
```

This is because you can pick k of them in `Binomial(n,k)` ways and then you know that there are `f(k)` BSTs for them.